# extern variable

Tags: c

how to use a variable defined in a header, and using them in multiple source files using extern.
I am getting multiple definition error.

Comment: c# dont know "headers" and you cant define variables without a class in c#.
this is a c or c++ question.

Comment: I've retagged it from C# to C, but it may be about C++ for all we know.

Comment: It is helpful, if you also post the errors you are getting.

Comment: it is important for us (geeks) to know your development environment (Visual Studio, gcc, etc)

Comment: please be elaborate in asking the questions; In this case, please mention the errors...

Comment: Sorry, that was a c question. I was new to stack overflow, so did ask question in that way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A good rule to follow is: "Don't *define* things in header files". *Declare* all you want but definitions should be restricted to non headers. A *declaration* is simply a notification that something exists. A *definition* actually defines what it is.

The rationale behind this guideline is to prevent exactly the situation you're seeing - having things define twice (or more) because header files are included into multiple compilation units.

To avoid this, you could use something like:

```
myprog.h:
    extern int myVar;     // a declaration.

myprog.c:
    #include "myprog.h"
    int myVar = 7;        // a definition.

otherbit.c:
    #include "myprog.h"
    int fn (void) {
        myVar = 12;
        return myVar;
    }
```

The definition above will only end up in `myprog.o`, you won't get another copy in `otherbit.o` to cause you problems at link time.

Leaving aside that proper encapsulation would make these global variables a very bad idea, that's the way I'd do it.

The *encapsulated* way of doing it would be something like this:

```
myprog.h:
    int getMyVar (void);
    void setMyVar (int);

myprog.c:
    #include "myprog.h"
    static int myVar = 7;
    int getMyVar (void) { return myVar; }
    void setMyVar (int n) {
        // Error checks on n here.
        myVar = n;
    }

otherbit.c:
    #include "myprog.h"
    int fn (void) {
        setMyVar (12);
        return getMyVar();
    }
```

Encapsulation is basically information hiding. It means you should expose as *little as possible* of your inner working to get the job done, lest you open yourself up the possibility of other code sneaking in under the covers and either invalidating your assumptions (see below) or making it harder to change your inner workings later.

A classic example is if you want the `myVar` variable restricted to the range 0 through 359 inclusive (say an angle). With encapsulation you could simply use:

```
void setMyVar (unsigned int n) { myVar = n % 360; }
```

and *never* have to worry about it being invalid. You can safely assume, memory corruption aside, that `myVar` will always be within the range desired. You would not have that certainty if some rogue piece of user code could come in and just do:

```
myVar = 32767;
```

without you knowing it. You would either have to cater for values outside your desired range or force it to the valid range at the start of all your functions:

```
myVar = myVar % 360;
```

That's poor coding practice, and totally unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, Thanks paxdiablo for your answer.
It helped me alot.